# Normal.dotm macro throws error opening protected document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I added the following macro to my Normal.dotm for Word 2010:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
'
' AutoOpen Macro
'
'
   Dim aStory As Range
   Dim aField As Field

   For Each aStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges

      For Each aField In aStory.Fields
         aField.Update
      Next aField

   Next aStory

 ' set document as unchanged (prevents save dialog popping up when closing) - further changes will set this back
 ActiveDocument.Saved = True
End Sub
```

Now when I open some documents in Word 2010, I get the following error message:

> Run-time error '4248'
>
> This command is not available because no document is open

So far this seems to occur for files that are opened in Protected view (e.g. files downloaded from the internet, or email attachments) - if I switch off Protected view in the Trust Centre the problem goes away.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft wrote a blog entry on [detecting whether Protected Mode is running from within a macro](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2010/09/13/object-model-considerations-for-protected-view-in-word-2010.aspx).

This shows that the value of `Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow` is `Nothing` when a document is **not** in Protected View.  So wrapping the macro functions that refer to ActiveDocument in If statements checking for this will prevent those functions from running when the document is in Protected view.

The above script becomes:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    '
    ' AutoOpen Macro
    '
    '
       Dim aStory As Range
       Dim aField As Field

    ' Check that document is not in Protected View before doing anything
    If Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow Is Nothing Then

           For Each aStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges

              For Each aField In aStory.Fields
                 aField.Update
              Next aField

           Next aStory

         ' set document as unchanged (prevents save dialog popping up when
         'closing) - further changes will set this back
         ActiveDocument.Saved = True
    End If
End Sub
```